# Using Modifiers of Perl-compatible Regex (PCRE) in grep

Tags: grep, perl, regex

According to `grep --help` and `man grep`, we can use the `-P` option in order to interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, to be precise), instead of the default [POSIX basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE).

In Perl language, various **[Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)** can be added to the expression, in order to adjust the pattern interpretation (in the syntax of `/pattern/modifiers`).

So, **how can someone add modifiers** to the grep's Perl regular expression? I tried some variations like `grep -P "/^got.it$/ms" [FILE]` but the search results were wrong.

However, about the PCRE interpretation, the manual points out that:

> *This is highly experimental and **grep -P** may warn of unimplemented features.*

Is it possible that the grep tool **does not support modifiers at all**?

By the way, I noticed that one can perform case-insensitive pattern matching by using the `-i` option, which is an example of a modifier.

Comment: Crossposted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110875/using-modifiers-of-perl-compatible-regex-pcre-in-grep/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the modifiers `imsxadlup` you can use the `(?X)` for as described in [Extended Patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns):

```
$ echo FOO | grep -P '(?i)foo'
FOO
```